# Python error: "IndexError: string index out of range"

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm currently learning python from a book called 'Python for the absolute beginner (third edition)'. There is an exercise in the book which outlines code for a hangman game. I followed along with this code however I keep getting back an error in the middle of the program.

Here is the code that is causing the problem:

```
if guess in word:
    print("\nYes!", guess, "is in the word!")

    # Create a new variable (so_far) to contain the guess
    new = ""
    i = 0
    for i in range(len(word)):
        if guess == word[i]:
            new += guess
        else:
            new += so_far[i]
        so_far = new
```

This is also the error it returns:

```
new += so_far[i]
IndexError: string index out of range
```

Could someone help me out with what is going wrong and what I can do to fix it?

edit: I initialised the so_far variable like so:

```
so_far = "-" * len(word)
```

Comment: This is minor and unrelated to your question, but you don't need the i = 0.  The for loop automatically sets the loop variable when it starts even if i hasn't been defined yet.

Comment: @Chad Yeah your right. I can't remember why I stuck that in :S

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It looks like you indented `so_far = new` too much. Try this:

```
if guess in word:
    print("\nYes!", guess, "is in the word!")

    # Create a new variable (so_far) to contain the guess
    new = ""
    i = 0
    for i in range(len(word)):
        if guess == word[i]:
            new += guess
        else:
            new += so_far[i]
    so_far = new # unindented this
```

Comment: Yes thank you so much! I find it a bit confusing to just have indentation for stuff that I would be used to putting curly brackets around!

Answer (score 6):

You are iterating over one string (`word`), but then using the index into that to look up a character in `so_far`. There is no guarantee that these two strings have the same length.

Answer (score 2):

This error would happen when the number of guesses (so_far) is less than the length of the word. Did you miss an initialization for the variable so_far somewhere, that sets it to something like

```
so_far = " " * len(word)
```

?

**Edit:**

try something like

```
print "%d / %d" % (new, so_far)
```

before the line that throws the error, so you can see exactly what goes wrong. The only thing I can think of is that so_far is in a different scope, and you're not actually using the instance you think.

Comment: Sorry I should have included this but forgot. I already had that variable initialised in the same way
    so_far = "-" * len(word)

Comment: Edited my response to add a way to debug, and another suggestion as to what may be wrong.

Comment: And it looks like @Rob Wouters got it, i missed that. He's right, so_far should be outside the for block :)

Answer (score 1):

There were several problems in your code.
Here you have a functional version you can analyze (Lets set 'hello' as the target word):

```
word = 'hello'
so_far = "-" * len(word)       # Create variable so_far to contain the current guess

while word != so_far:          # if still not complete
    print(so_far)
    guess = input('>> ')       # get a char guess

    if guess in word:
        print("\nYes!", guess, "is in the word!")

        new = ""
        for i in range(len(word)):  
            if guess == word[i]:
                new += guess        # fill the position with new value
            else:
                new += so_far[i]    # same value as before
        so_far = new
    else:
        print("try_again")

print('finish')
```

I tried to write it for py3k with a py2k ide, be careful with errors.

Comment: Yeah I only took out a small segment of code to get to the point. Thanks for pointing it out though.