# Selection of lowercase words in a list on python

Tags: python, string, list

I defined a function that splits paragraphs from a text file into a list of words, but now i want to select only words that start with lowercase letters and i am not sure how to do that.

```
 #..................................................................findCommonWords
def findCommonWords(paragraphs):
    for paragraph in paragraphs:
        words = list(paragraph.split(' '))
        for word in words:
           eachword = list(word.split(' '))
           print(eachword)
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to use `islower()` function.

```
>>> words = ['One', 'Two', 'Three', 'four']
>>> [i for i in words if i[0].islower()]
['four']
>>>
```

This would print only the words which starts with an lower case letter. `i[0].islower()` returns true only if the first letter is in lower case form.

Comment: Thank you, but i tried this it gives me an error message.                                        lowercase_words = [word for word in words if word[0].islower()]
IndexError: string index out of range

Comment: post a sample input data. And also check http://stackoverflow.com/q/8712659/3297613

Comment: >>>> def findCommonWords(paragraphs):
                for paragraph in paragraphs:
                      words = list(paragraph.split(' '))
                      for word in words:
                            newword = (word for word in words if word[0].islower())
                            print(newword)