# Index error in Python: "string index out of range"

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm a beginner programmer and as practice I want to make a code that would print every word in a sentence into a new line given that the word starts with h-z.

Here's the code I made:

```py
random_phrase = "Wheresoever you go, go with all your heart"
word = ""
for ltr in random_phrase:
    if ltr.isalpha():
        word += ltr
    else:
        if word.lower()[0] > "g":
            print(word)
            word = ""
        else:
            word = ""
```

After it prints you, there's a line of empty space, then the index error occurs. What did I do wrong?

Comment: what is your expected output?

Comment: Duplicate of [Python error: “IndexError: string index out of range”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8712659/python-error-indexerror-string-index-out-of-range)

Comment: [Try your code here](http://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=edit)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- In your original code, you have a `,` which is causing your code to break, since it is not an alphanumeric character, so it goes into the else loop, where your `word` is an empty string, and when you try to get the first element is a empty string, you get `IndexError`. Hence it is better to check for a non-whitespace character like `if ltr != ' ':` .
- You can reset `word = ""` outside `if` condition
- Your code doesn't check the last word in the string, which you can do after your for loop finishes

So your refactored code will look like

```
random_phrase = "Wheresoever you go go with all your heart"
word = ""
for ltr in random_phrase:
    #Check for non-whitespace character
    if ltr != ' ':
        word += ltr
    else:
        #Check if word starts with g
        if word.lower()[0] > "g":
            print(word)
        #Reset word variable
        word = ""

#Check the last word
if word.lower()[0] > "g":
    print(word)
```

The output will be

```
Wheresoever
you
with
your
heart
```

You can simplify your code a lot by splitting your string into words, by using `string.split`, iterating through the words, and then checking if the first character of each word lies in `h-z`

```
random_phrase = "Wheresoever you go, go with all your heart"

#Split string into words
words = random_phrase.split()

#Iterate through every word
for word in words:

    #If the first character of the word lies between h-z, print it
    if word.lower()[0] > "g":
        print(word)
```

Here your output will be

```
Wheresoever
you
with
your
heart
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this to print every word of a sentence that starts with h-z:

```
import string
# make the sentence lower case
random_phrase = "Wheresoever you go, go with all your heart".lower()
# split the sentence with space as separator into a list
words = random_phrase.split(" ")
start = "h"
end = "z"
# string.ascii_lowercase will give the lowercase letters ‘abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz’
letters = string.ascii_lowercase
# take the range h-z
allowed = letters[letters.index(start):letters.index(end)+1]
# iterate through each word and check if it starts with (h-z)
for word in words:
    if any(word.startswith(x) for x in allowed):
        print(word)
```

Using regular expressions:

```
import re
random_phrase = "Wheresoever you go, go with all your heart"
words = [s for s in random_phrase.split() if re.match('^[h-z,H-Z]', s)]
for word in words:
    print(word)
```

Comment: Thank you! Works well. I'm trying to do this exercise without import keywords, but this is great.

Answer (score 1):

> What did I do wrong?

When your process encounters the comma (not-alpha) after the word `go` it determines that `go` does not start with a letter greater than `'g'` so it assigns an empty string to `word` (`else; word = ''`). The next item is a space which is not-alpha and it tries to compare the first letter of `word` which is an empty string (`''[0] > 'g'`) so it causes an IndexError.

You can fix it by checking to see if `word` is an empty string before the comparison.
Change

```
if word.lower()[0] > "g":
```

to

```
if word and word.lower()[0] > "g":
```

---

[An empty string evaluates to a boolean False](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing):

```
>>> s = ''
>>> bool(s)
False
>>>
```

`and` is a [boolean operation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#boolean-operations); `x and y` will evaluate to `False` if either term is False - `x` is evaluated first; if it is `False`, its value will be returned and `y` will not be evaluated. This is referred to as [*short circuit* behavior.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2580136/does-python-support-short-circuiting)

```
>>> x = ''
>>> y = 'foo'
>>> x and y
''
>>> bool(x and y)
False
>>> if x and y:
...     print(True)
... else:
...     print(False)

False
>>>
```

My *fix* for your conditional statement relies on the short-circuit behavior so that `word[0]...` won't be evaluated if `word` is an empty string. Your `else` clause could be written a little more explicit - something like:

```
....
    else:
        if not word:
            pass
        elif word.lower()[0] > "g":
            print(word)
        word = ""
```

but for some reason I didn't like how that looked.

Comment: This is great! Thank you. If I may ask, however, how does simply writing "word and" check if it is an empty string?

Comment: You can simpilfy your code a lot by splitting string into words, and checking for the condition! @JillandJill Check my answer if it makes sense to you!

Answer (score 0):

I think the error occurs because of this chunk of the code:

```
    if word.lower()[0] > "g":
        print(word)
        word = ""
    else:
        word = ""
```

You're reseting the `word` variable into a blank. Indexing on a blank does not work (as you can see when you try executing this code):

```
word = ""
word[0]

IndexError: string index out of range
```

Answer (score 0):

Always go for simple solutions...

```
phrase = "Wheresoever you go, go with all your heart"
for word in (phrase.lower()).split():
   first_letter = word[0]
   if first_letter > "g":
      print(word)
```