# How can i get the sum string using python?

Tags: python-3.x, string

Here is my program I want to find the weather it is a sum string or not based on the following condition
1)the string length must be >3 
example:"12358" --- 1+2=3,2+3=5,3+5=8
I tried this program I am getting the index error please help me.Thank you in adavnce.

Given below is my code:

```
y="12358"
for i in range(len(y)-1):
    if y[i]+y[i+1]==y[i+2]:
        print "sum stringgg"
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python error: "IndexError: string index out of range"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8712659/python-error-indexerror-string-index-out-of-range)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The upper bound of the range should be the length of `y` minus 2 instead to accommodate the comparison with the item of the index plus 2. You should also convert each character in the string to an integer for arithmetic addition and comparison. Finally, you should use the `for-else` construct to `break` whenever the former two digits do not add up to the latter digit, and only output `'sum string'` if the loop finishes without `break`:

```
y = "12358"
digits = list(map(int, y))
for i in range(len(digits) - 2):
    if digits[i] + digits[i + 1] != digits[i + 2]:
        break
else:
    print('sum string')
```